# Javascript not making div show

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble making a div show up using javascript.

```
<div class=" notification success">
 <a href="#" class="close-notification" title="Hide Notification" rel="tooltip">x</a>
 <p>An email has been sent confirming your identity.</p></div> 

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
     var notification = '.notification';
      $(notification).show();      
</script>       
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YBkqg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your jquery js in a document.ready() otherwise you cant ensure that the DOM is fully loaded and ready.

Your need is just a one liner like so

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.notification').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have double or single quotes surrounding the selector if you're naming a specific element ("#id", ".class").

Best way to do this is to avoid using the variable. It's just three extra characters anyways.

Also, put your code into a `$(document).ready(function(){});` function like this:

```
$(document).ready(funciton(){
  $(".notification").show();
});
```

To minimize the amount of code you're putting in, you can just use this instead:

```
$(function(){
  $(".notification").show();
});
```

`$(function(){});` can replace `$(document).ready()`, as by default jQuery selects the document.